# How do I restart the sshd service without logging in to the server?

Tags: linux, sshd

I have stopped the sshd service on my Linux box and now I cannot connect to the server through PuTTY or any other tools.

How do I now restart this service?

Comment: Simple answer is that you don't. Rebooting the server one way or the other would most likely kick back sshd too as it's most likely one of the services automatically started on boot, but this might not be a good move in case we're talking about production server. You should get on the console.

Comment: so you do not have telnet running and are not physically at the server?

Comment: This is a VM in some remote location.telnet is not running, how do i remotely reboot this server, though this is a productin server, i guess i have no option left

Answer (score 1):

You need physical access to the machine to restart the sshd service unless you have telnet or some other remote service running that also would give you shell access.

Comment: This is a VM and telnet is also not running. What do i do now?

Comment: Remote login to the hypervisor to access the vm as if you were local. 

What type of vm are you running?